# How to gamify security page?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-expectation, security, gamification

I need some idea to gamify security page in my account section to urge user to make use of all  products  that are offer to them such as 2 pin verification, password strength and others.   It will also put message that user are partially responsible for their page too .

How can I  gamify this security page and ideas without saying your profile is 20% secure ( his can show user that my platform is not secured?

Should go for like status bar low, medium, high on the left to gamify as in implementing business rules and telling user to make use of all security products available to them ? Any suggestion would be much-appreciated :)

Comment: You need a couple of months of research if you want to get a valid answer. Asking here will only bias your future decisions because people here won't know your context, users, time/resources available, and many other variables. It is very hard to get a gamified experience successful!

Comment: I wouldn't gamify something so simple. You probably have less than a half dozen things you're concerned about, right? Then display a little box off to the side with the items in a list checked off according to what the user has done to secure their account. At the bottom of the list, provide a link to a Wizard that will take them through the options. This is what Google does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents.

You can gamify via **achievements, rewards, or comparing to others (leaderboards)** (there's of course endless other ways but these are the most common broad categories).

**Leaderboards** - 
In a security system I wouldn't compare users security to others, being on the bottom of said leaderboard means you have low security, thus you become a target.

**Rewards** - 
If you can offer rewards for being more secure then that will obviously encourage users to participate. This can be rewards like "Great you've enabled two-step authentication, by helping us save money on fraud-protection you've qualified for $X of your subscription fee!". Or since you mentioned the users are being held liable you can phrase that as the reward "Woo! You enabled SMS authentication, your fraudulent-charge liability deductible has decreased by 5%!" (obviously I'm just making words up).

**Achievments** - Finally, if you can't give out tangible rewards you can make up rewards in the form of achievements. This will be less enticing than actually receiving a reward but getting the curiosity of "what are these badges" "what will I get" should be enough to get more engagement. Flash up a little badge icon that says "You're password has 200bits of entropy, you've unlocked the **Bank Vault Badge**, unlock more badges by ..."